# Hostname bindings for IIS in Sitecore Azure PaaS

Tags: azure, iis

For Sitecore Azure (up to 8.1) how are the hostnames configured for Azure PaaS CD environments? Is this something which happens automatically based on settings found in Sitecore.config/Web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the hostnames in the portal (or via PowerShell) first. This will involve a DNS validation step so you will need access to your DNS provider as well.

You only need hostnames in the Sitecore Config if your system needs to differentiate site content between several domain names. If it's just the one, you only need to configure the Azure website.

PS Azure Website-grade PaaS is only officially supported from 8.2.1  Be careful when running multiple instances as there are Sitecore components that use the file system for storage and Azure PaaS had a shared filesystem across instances.

Comment: This answer was downvoted but nobody bothered to leave a comment as to why.  Clearly someone doesn't agree my statements (from 2 years ago) - it would be very helpful to future visitors if you identified _in what way_ the above is incorrect, not relevant or off topic. I don't have the rep to see who downvoted, but you know who you are.  Having re-read the answer, it still seems right to me, with the possible exception that you don't *have* to configure hostnames first, you can configure them at any time really, it's just you have to configure them before you can use them obviously.